# Capacitor discharging time

Tags: capacitor, ac, discharge

What is the time needed for discharging, when a charged capacitor is connected to an uncharged one in a circuit along with an AC voltage source?
Since a lot of people asked to give more information about my doubt, I was watching professor Behzad Razavis video on voltage doublers whose link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uni-behIRN4 at the 54th min in this video the circuit is simplified into the circuit I have drawn, so in this even though one capacitor already has a charge over it, he said that the whole capacitive circuit works as a voltage divider for only the input voltage  and I think he ignored the voltage already present on the capacitor. Can any one look into this please?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr3mv0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This circuit is not physical, you need to add some resistances

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This appears to be a homework question with no effort made, expecting mountains of effort from other people. Please edit your question to show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Since you have already connected the circuit in *Circuitlab*, you can simulate this circuit in *Circuitlab* to find out the time needed for discharging!

Comment: And the source impedance of V1 could also affect the equalization behavior.

Comment: What did your (mandatory) simulation reveal?

Comment: @winny i got my ans as in ideal case the distarge would be instantaneous ,but my real doubt was regarding the lecture whose link i have provided .

Answer (score 3):

In the ideal circuit you've drawn, the discharge will be (ideally) instantaneous.

In a real circuit, resistance and inductance will give you a finite time for discharge.